# Ruby Cucumber - Running using Cucumber::Runtime(config).run! - 'Officially supported'?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a test farm I'm making that can run Cucumber tests and will take the results and write to a database.

Instead of using backticks to run from the command line I'm considering this, which seemed to work rather well from an `irb` prompt:

```
config = {paths: ['.\\scenarios\\my.feature'], filters: [], tag_expressions: ['@open_print_pdf'],tag_limits: [], profiles: ['example'], require: []}
Cucumber::Runtime.new(Cucumber::Configuration.new(config)).run!
```

I like that I then get some objects that I can interrogate to write things I need to the db like:

- steps
- feature and scenario name
- etc.

Before I considered this I was going to run using the JSON formatter, save the file, and then parse it, make it a hash and send to db.

Is the only supported way to run it through the command line. I find it useful to programmatically run it so I have everything I need without needing to do needless IO.

So, is running using `Cucumber::Runtime(config).run!` officially supported?

Comment: I'd ask this on the Cucumber mailing list, your more likely to get an official response there